# Where is the daemon folder in Debian

Tags: debian, directory, daemon, file-location

I have just installed a daemon with:

```
apt-get install daemon
```

and the script I am using requires the directory of daemon's installation.  Where is this, or how do I find it?

Comment: Do you need daemon's installation or its path? I'm pretty sure you need the path which is available by typing `which daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

Find downloaded package in apt cache:

```
ls -alF /var/cache/apt/archives | grep daemon
```

If you already cleared apt cache, try to redownload package:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install daemon
```

Then check contents of this package and file paths after installation:

```
sudo dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/daemon_0.6.4-1_amd64.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-06-14 23:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-06-14 23:55 ./etc/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       141 2010-06-14 23:55 ./etc/daemon.conf
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-06-14 23:55 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-06-14 23:55 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    187080 2010-06-14 23:55 ./usr/bin/daemon
...
```

I think the answer is **/usr/bin**.

**Update:**

The above version of `daemon` package actual for Debian 7.3